# django filter many-to-many with given list

Tags: python, django, object, filter, many-to-many

I would like to `filter` a Django model that is connected to a second model via a many-to-many intermediate relationship.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

[design and expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqwej.png)

The result should be to select only Person A because he is connected to Groups with entries 1 AND 2 through the membership. I'd like to use `Q` objects for this kind of task.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want all the `Person` objects which are in all the group Ids you will provide it to.

**Solution**:

```
from django.db.models import Q

person_qs = Person.objects.exclude(~(Q(group__id=1) & Q(group__id=2)))
```

Here, I used `exclude` to exclude all the group Ids which are not 1 and 2.

If you have lots of group Ids, you can use `reduce` and `operator` to build the query in a single for-loop.

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

query = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(group__id=group_id) for group_id in group_ids))

persons_qs = Person.objects.exclude(~query)
```

This, will form the query like `Q(group__id=1) & Q(group_id=2) &` (so on...)

Comment: Hi Sachin, can you explain why you didn't go through a regular filter instead used exclude and negate operator?

Comment: `exclude` and `filter` form two different queries. What `exclude` does, in this case, is that it runs a sub-query for each group like `WHERE NOT (NOT (EXISTS(SELECT(1) from membership_table M1 where group_id = 1 and person.id = M1.person_id) AND NOT (EXISTS ...`, while `filter` does an INNER JOIN with membership table and does `WHERE membership_table.group_id = 1 AND membership_table.group_id = 2`, so you can see that the `filter` operation is wrong, as the same membership row cannot have two different group ids.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use Q here, it is a simple query.

```
Person.objects.filter(group__id__in=[1, 2])
```

Comment: But this would return B aswell correct as IN acts like OR?